# Zabbix agent on is unreachable for 5 minutes

Tags: zabbix

I used zabbix 2.4 and it worked perfectly. I decided to upgrade server and all agents to 3.0 LTS. I did not change any settings in agents and server conf-files and did not change any settings wia web.

But now I receive messages

> Zabbix agent %servername% on is unreachable for 5 minutes

This agent works on the same machine with zabbix-server. More strange that I receive other messages from this agent. So I can see that agent works and server can communicate with it.

After I started to receive this error message I tried to change IP of agent. First it was 127.0.0.1, after I changed address to network's IP: 192.168.x.x. Nothing changed. I receive unreachable message every 6-7 minutes with the other messages from this agent. And also this agent is green via web-interface.

```
zabbix_get -s 127.0.0.1 -k agent.ping
```

also returns `1`.

How to fix problem?

Comment: Have you only one agent? If not are the other agents working? Have you tried the enable debug-verbose logging on the agent?

Comment: set DebugLevel=4 and check agent logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I increased Timeout and error has gone

Comment: which Timeout value did you increase? the 5m for the trigger?

Comment: No, just parameter "Timeout" in zabbix_agentd.conf. Was 3, now 30.

Answer (score 0):

take zabbix server restart and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check also zabbix_agentd.conf and replace valid IP and name